# Sundew leaves are becoming brown - should I move it to a larger pot?

Tags: repotting

Three months ago, we bought [this sundew](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drosera_aliciae.jpg) in a small pot. As told by the seller, we watered it with purified water poured below the pot. Now, its leaves are becoming brown:
[image]

I thought that maybe I should move it to a larger pot. But, I was told that it needs sterile soil, and all I found in the gardening stores was the usual soil (that comes with some fertilizers).

What should I do? Is it a good idea to move the sundew to a somewhat larger pot with a standard gardening soil?

EDIT: I understand that standard gardening soil is not good for a sundew. I did not find clean soil in gardening stores. Where can I find clean soil? Can I e.g. collect sand from the seashore?

Comment: From what little I can see, this plant is full of fungus from too much water.  I don't like the watering from below especially with a pot that tall in relation to the roots of the plant.  Allowing the plant to SIT in water for a long time will certainly be a canvas for fungus and root rot.  Remove the plant, cut the crappy leaves off, knock off excess soil, use new potting soil, no rock or gravel at the bottom and get a terracotta low, squat pot.  Water from above.  Water only when the soil dries out 1/2 inch below the surface.  Same size pot only shorter!  Clay pots add more air to the soil.

Comment: I'm unconvinced there is a fungal problem, but the photo is blurry under magnification making it hard to tell, can you post another photo showing the leaves a bit closer in? These plants require high humidity and don't like to dry out, but have you been leaving it sitting in water at the bottom?

Comment: @Bamboo Yes, I have been leaving it sitting in water at the bottom, as I was told by the seller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most carnivorous plants grow in soil that has very, very low nutrients, hence their need to get nutrients from bugs. Garden soil is probably too high in nutrients and may be wrong for your plant.

Read more here:

- [Sundew plant care](http://www.mycarnivore.com/carnivorous-plants-for-sale/sundew-plants-for-sale/sundew-plant-care)
- [Sundews](http://www.thegardenhelper.com/sundew.html)
- [Grow Sundews](http://www.growsundews.com/)

Comment: Strangely, I could not find clean soil in any gardening store near my house. How can I get such soil? Can I just e.g. collect sand from the seashore? Alternatively, can I take usual garden soil and clean it somehow?